# Stuck with cloudfront aws custom port

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I created a network load balancer with EC2 instance and then I added listener with custom port 5000. I was successfully access load balancer dns with port 5000. I also created cloudfront linked with this load balancer but it seemed that AWS only supports port 80 or 443. Could anyone open custom port? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From [Values That You Specify When You Create or Update a Distribution - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesDomainName):

> **HTTP Port:** The HTTP port that the custom origin listens on. Valid values include ports 80, 443, and 1024 to 65535. The default value is port 80.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved my problem, I used postman to load url and after that I tried to load url from browser then it works.